# mark values on a plot using geom_boxplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

that's a part of the data frame i have:

```
   Y       X      
1 0.2342 0.49530177
2 0.5628 0.61576918
3 0.3249 0.73623660
4 0.5234 0.85670401
5 1.2354 0.97717143
6 2.3423 0.09763884
```

and i also have another data frame:

```
       start   end  name
    1 0.0123 0.123  A1
    2 0.5352 0.714  A2
    3 0.6239 0.789  B4
    4 0.6985 0.818  D2
    5 0.1264 0.216  V4
    6 0.1932 0.217  H4
```

so i plotted the first data frame correctly. but what i want to do is to mark the name from the second data frame on the x-axis of the plot of the first one.

e.g.(make a geom_box or geom_error bar form 0.0123 to 0.123 and write A1, etc... for all the parts of the second data frame) so the boxplots or the error bars should be horizontal(parallel with the x-axis)

how this can be done??

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, the data you have in the second data-frame are the errors of the observations in the first one (or something similar). If that is the case, I would recommend to combine both dataframes first. Then, assuming your dataframes are D1 and D2, the following code plots the data and the error bars, while 'flipping' the coordinates.

```
# Create artificial data
D1 <- data.frame(X= 1:100, Y = rnorm(100))
D2 <- data.frame(start= D1$Y - abs(rnorm(100, 10)), end = D1$Y + abs(rnorm(100, 10)), name = sample(c('A','B', 'C', 'D', 'E'), 100, rep = TRUE))

# First step: Combine the two data frames
D3 <- data.frame(D1, D2)

# Plot data
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(D3) +
    geom_point(aes(x = X, y = Y)) + # Plots the points
    geom_errorbar(aes(x = X, ymax = start, ymin = end, width = 1)) + # Creates the errorbars
    coord_flip() # Flips the coordinates
```

Comment: thank you. that's what i want but the idea is that the first data frame is much bigger than the second data frame. and i want to display the the values in the 2nd one on the plot of the first one. and btw i want them based on the x-axis and not the y-axis

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are wanting the final plot to look like, especially since the intervals in your example overlap.  Here is one possibility:

```
DF1 <-
structure(list(Y = c(0.2342, 0.5628, 0.3249, 0.5234, 1.2354, 
2.3423), X = c(0.49530177, 0.61576918, 0.7362366, 0.85670401, 
0.97717143, 0.09763884)), .Names = c("Y", "X"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
DF2 <-
structure(list(start = c(0.0123, 0.5352, 0.6239, 0.6985, 0.1264, 
0.1932), end = c(0.123, 0.714, 0.789, 0.818, 0.216, 0.217), name = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 5L), .Label = c("A1", "A2", "B4", "D2", "H4", 
"V4"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("start", "end", "name"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6"))
```

Make a graph with

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=DF1, aes(X, Y)) +
  geom_errorbarh(data=DF2, aes(xmax=end, xmin=start, x=(start+end)/2, y=0)) +
  geom_text(data=DF2, aes(x=(start+end)/2, y=0, label=name))
```

[image]

You can use color to try and distinguish the bars at the bottom, but if there are very many of them it will quickly not be distinguishable.

```
ggplot() + 
  geom_point(data=DF1, aes(X, Y)) +
  geom_errorbarh(data=DF2, aes(xmax=end, xmin=start, x=(start+end)/2, y=0, colour=name)) +
  geom_text(data=DF2, aes(x=(start+end)/2, y=0, label=name, colour=name)) +
  scale_colour_discrete(guide="none")
```

[image]